# Codeigniter link to load different view

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. Everything looks fine. But I keep getting Error 500 on the page load.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() 
    {
        $this->home();
    }

public function home()
    {
        $this->load->view("header");
        $this->load->view("site");
        $this->load->view("footer");
    }

public function about()
    {
        $this->load->view("header");
        $this->load->view("about");
        $this->load->view("footer");
    }
}
```

If I go to link mywebsite.com/site/about

I will get a 500 Internal Server Error

What am I doing wrong?

My htaccess file looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|scripts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Ideas? thoughts. I know it' something stupid. I haven't done any CI work in a couple months.

Thanks

Comment: Plz check the file names and folder structure

Answer (score 0):

1) Are your CI folders located in the root folder or is it in the folder "site"?

2) If in the folder "site" try to use mywebsite.com/site/your_controller_name/about
   Also try mywebsite.com/index.php/site/about or mywebsite.com/site/index.php/your_controller_name/about

How I call it: mywebsite.com/CodeIgniter/Welcome/About 
The CI files are located in the folder 'CodeIgniter' and this is what my .httaccess looks like: http://pastebin.com/30TReyqe

Comment: The about.php file is in my views directory. This is also where my site.php file is that loads fine. Just when I want to load the about.php file I get the error which is weird.

Comment: Well I found out what the issue is kinda. Locally using WAMP everything works. But on my hosting company (godaddy) it does not work. Any ideas what that might be?

Comment: one thing 500 error code doesn't mean file doesn't exist, if the file doesn't exist, it should be 404 or code in 400 range. If it's 500 range probably, need to do with server side congiguration. such as memory need to be allocated in php file and etc.

Comment: @menukadevinda  Sorry my bad, I just woke up when I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was. It was something with the htaccess file

I had to do this to get it to work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Thanks